# onchange not working for drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it so that when a selection is made from my dropdown menu, text will display accordingly inside my textarea, for now I've been trying to just get one of them to work.

PROBLEM: It won't display the string from the array inside the textarea. Is the problem within this code?

The drop down menu:

```
<select id="dropdown" onchange="getFrames();">
    <option value="1" selected="selected"> Blank </option>
    <option value="2"> Exercise </option>
    <option value="3"> Juggler </option>
    <option value="4"> Bike </option>
    <option value="5"> Dive </option>
</select>
```

The textarea :

```
<textarea id="textstage" rows="80" cols="20"> </textarea>
```

JavaScript :

I have these global variables.

```
var theStage = document.getElementById("textstage");
var getDrop = document.getElementById("dropdown");
```

and then I have this function.

```
function getFrames(){
    var dropSel = getDrop.options[getDrop.selectedIndex].value;

    if(dropSel === 2){
        theStage.value = ANIMATIONS["Exercise"];
}
```

The array being referenced is a global array from another js file.

Comment: Is the control going into getFrames method ? I mean , did you try putting an alert in that method and check if the event is getting triggered ?

Comment: When I implement the alert in the same section as if(dropSel === 2){ no alert happens when I change the selected option to exercise in the drop down menu.

Comment: @Corjava Do you see any error in your console?

Comment: there is an error . Close the method

Comment: @harsha Well, that was one issue, but I just closed it and it still hasn't worked.

Comment: Include that method after your html content is in place :-)

Comment: @Corjava `"2" === 2` will be false. Also you just need to get the text of your option right not the value? Plus your `document.getElementById` part should be within the window.onload or should appear after the element in the html. And getFrames must be defined in the global scope

Comment: @PSL I've changed it to == this would fix it correct? Because it will ignore type?

Comment: @Corjava Yes that should. But we are not sure what is your issue. You need to debug a bit more or make it replicable in a fiddle. See the demo in my answer.

Comment: @PSL interestingly enough I'm getting undefined inside of the textarea, atleast it's showing something.

Comment: @Corjava How does your object `ANIMATIONS` look like. If i were you, I would check that to see if the object has the key `Exercise`

Comment: @PSL This is the page my professor supplied me for this assignment, inside is the array. (nearbottom)
http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/12sp/homework/6/animations.js

Comment: @Corjava Then why are you getting the value as `ANIMATIONS["Exercise"]`

Comment: @PSL The second paragraph at the top of the page convinced me that I should do it that way, maybe I misunderstand it?

Comment: @Corjava Here it is working http://jsfiddle.net/wRCMW/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var theStage,getDrop; 

function getFrames() {
    var dropSel = getDrop.options[getDrop.selectedIndex].innerHTML;//+getDrop.value;
    theStage.value = ANIMATIONS[dropSel];

}

//Place the selection part on load callback
window.onload = function () {
    theStage = document.getElementById("textstage");
    getDrop = document.getElementById("dropdown");
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4E4Y7/)**

- You can just use `getDrop.value` instead of doing `getDrop.options[getDrop.selectedIndex].value`.
- `===` is strict equality comparison meaning "2" === 2 will be false as in your case.
- Seems like you are looking for the option text to look up the value based on this as key in your object Animation. So you can just do `getDrop.options[getDrop.selectedIndex].innerHTML`
- Your document selection code should be inside window.onload or after the element in the html

Answer (score 0):

I made a minor change to your html by omitting the inline event handler, and instead added it to the javascript.

**html:**

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="1" selected="selected"> Blank </option>
    <option value="2"> Exercise </option>
    <option value="3"> Juggler </option>
    <option value="4"> Bike </option>
    <option value="5"> Dive </option>
</select>
<textarea id="textstage" rows="80" cols="20"> </textarea>
```

Also, in the javascript, I took away the strict equality (===) and made it just (==).

**javascript:**

```
var theStage = document.getElementById("textstage");
var getDrop = document.getElementById("dropdown");
getDrop.addEventListener("change",getFrames);
function getFrames(){
   var dropSel = getDrop.options[getDrop.selectedIndex].value;
    if(dropSel == 2){
      theStage.value = ANIMATIONS["Exercise"];
    }
}
```

Hopefully it should work now for you.